removing 0 from the list in python
How can I fix this to not include zero answers as 'a' and 'b' aren't 0 but when running the code it gives 0 as one of the answers?
def determinate(a,b):
    return a * (3*2 - 0*2) - 0 * (4*2 - b*2) + b * (4*0 - 3*b)

for a in range(-100,101):
    for b in range(-100,101):
        if determinate(a,b) == 0:
            print(f"a: {a}, b: {b}")

and this is what it gave me:
a: 0, b: 0
a: 2, b: -2
a: 2, b: 2
a: 8, b: -4
a: 8, b: 4
a: 18, b: -6
a: 18, b: 6
a: 32, b: -8
a: 32, b: 8
a: 50, b: -10
a: 50, b: 10
a: 72, b: -12
a: 72, b: 12
a: 98, b: -14
a: 98, b: 14

but I want to remove the a:0, b:0

Just add to the if condition a != 0 and b!=0 and determinate(a,b) == 0:

Overly pedantic sidenote which may nevertheless be helpful: there's no list here. You're printing each value, but you're not actually building a list out of them.

I have found a piece of code that you could optimize: 0 * (4*2 - b*2). Or is that a typo? ;)

Yeah, as written the determinate formula simplifies to 6*a - 3*b^2, I believe. Perhaps some of those values are hard-coded "parameters".

def determinate(a, b):
    return a * (3 * 2 - 0 * 2) - 0 * (4 * 2 - b * 2) + b * (4 * 0 - 3 * b)


for a in range(-100, 101):
    for b in range(-100, 101):
        if determinate(a, b) != 0:
            continue
        if a == 0 and b == 0:
            continue
        print(f"a: {a:3},    b: {b:3}")

